# Restoring my original keyboard mapping without logging in

Tags: xmodmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restoring my original keyboard mapping without logging on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159961/restoring-my-original-keyboard-mapping-without-logging-on)

I used `xmodmap` to remap some keys. I followed directions to restart. Now, I can't log in.

How can I restore my previous keyboard mapping?

Comment: What exactly did you do with `xmodmap`? The effect of the `xmodmap` command doesn't last after you log out, so you must have saved a file somewhere. Why can't you log in? Because you can't find the right keys to type your password?

Comment: I didn't save any file...