# Restoring my original keyboard mapping without logging on

Tags: xmodmap

I used xmodmap to remap some keys. I followed directions to restart. Now, I can't log in.

How can I restore my previous keyboard mapping?

Answer (score 4):

Reboot.

Press and hold the left Shift key.

Look for the kernel that ends in (recovery mode) and load it.

[image]

Now drop to a root shell.

[image]

Then move to the user directory in question and delete the .Xmodmap file.